# Is there a difference in performance between :not([attr="value"]) and [attr!="value"]?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a difference in performance between

```
:not([attr="value"])
```

and

```
[attr!="value"]
```

? Does the **CSS3** spec recommend one alternative over the other?

*EDIT:*

The CSS3 spec does not include a `[attr!="value"]` selector. This is just something that jQuery implements.

So, question should be is there a difference in performance between

```
$(':not([attr="value"])')
```

and

```
$('[attr!="value"]')
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery tries to use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` whenever it is possible, as this uses the native browser capabilities to execute a query.

If something is not in the specs or not supported by the browser then jQuery needs to fallback to the [Swizzle engine](http://sizzlejs.com/), which generally would be slower as it needs to travers the DOM itself.

The code flow would be something like this (pseudocode):

```
try {
     document.querySelectorAll(selector);
} catch ( e ) {
     Swizzle.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Therefore for browsers that support `:not([attr="value"])` it should (if implemented well) be faster then `[attr!="value"]`.

Whether this would be noticeable depends on the use-case.